# How can the A and B models of the 42055 Bucket Wheel Excavator be modded to fit together?

Tags: compatibility, set-modification

The [42055 Bucket Wheel Excavator](https://brickset.com/sets/42055-1) [image: 42055 A model - Bucket Wheel Excavator]has a B model, a mobile aggregate grader: [image: 42055 B model - mobile aggregate grader] which shares the mining theme with the A model and seems to be designed to sort the mixed output of the excavator into smaller and larger pieces.

But as the [Brickset review states](https://brickset.com/article/23024/42055-b-model-mobile-aggregate-grader):

> Unfortunately the chute is too high for the BWEs exit conveyor to feed into it if both are on level ground. Its edges are about 21cm from the ground; the bottom of the BWEs conveyer is about 18cm.

How can one modify either or both models in order to make them compatible with each other? The obvious solution would be to raise the A model on a platform of some kind, but I would prefer some kind of more natural solution.

Comment: "Is it possible to modify?" - that's an odd question for LEGO set as everything is possible and of course it can be modified. You can make one's end longer/shorter to fit the needed height.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, updated the question.

Comment: @Alex I am amazed by the number of questions in which people ask whether LEGO can be modified, but I also see where they're coming from, because after spending a long time to build one of these beautiful designs - especially the really big ones - you don't want to tear it apart again!

Comment: That said, from the picture it looks like the excavator's conveyor belt isn't held on by very much. You might just be able to replace some beams with longer ones. Or, the grader's belt is obviously connected with linear actuators - can they not be extended any further to lower the belt? If the grader's belt was flat then I can't imagine how it would possibly not be low enough.

Comment: I'm well aware of the fact that LEGO can be modified, I'm asking what would be the best way to achieve this. The grader should be receiving the pieces in the output stream of the BWE in its hopper. Whose lips are positioned higher than the output conveyor belt of the BWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found someone in [this video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=khDTwVbmemg) doing that mod.

---

The modification consists of removing a part of the hopper wall to let the BWE drop it's output into it from the side.

These are the relevant pictures:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice first post Mr. Zasepa... or is this really Zovlty in disguise?  Very funny! Get that hat!

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the author has removed a part of the wall from the hopper on the grader to make room for the BWE's output chute. It'd be nice if it came with more detailed pictures or instructions, but we the is much more than I got so far, so here's your checkmark :) Happy New Year!

Comment: It would be better to include the essential parts in your answer, link-only answers are discouraged, and can lead to problems with [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: @RinRio-Oki I'm well aware that using sockpuppet accounts is an offense worth suspension, and thus definitely goes against the spirits and rules of Winter Bash and Bricks.SE in general. Considering that there is a mandatory time limit before a bounty can be awarded, I can't even get a hat from this interaction, which makes the idea even more baffling. But I got an answer to my question, which is what the site is about after all :) I can't fault you for suspecting foul play though, I too have seen my own share of questionable behavior during these weeks, which should thankfully end soon.